# Magento - get the "not formatted" prices

Tags: magento

how can I get the not formatted prices (without currency and without the separator of thousands) ?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the product instance you can always do

```
$product->getPrice();
```

and then format it as you want

Comment: Thanks, how can I format it to have the current locale and currency ??

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php echo number_format($_product->getFinalPrice(),2);?>
```

That should work too!